# Methods vs Attributes Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Was debating with a colleague of mine tonight on methods vs attributes in Rails.  I swear I have seen this before unless I am crazy.  Here is an example:

We have a user model and we want to be certain we have a first name and a last name prior to saving the record.  I hate callbacks, but for this example, let's say it is in a before_save callback.

```
class User     
  before_save :set_first_last

  def set_first_last
    first_name if self.first_name.blank?
    last_name if self.last_name.blank?
  end

  def first_name
    self.first_name = self.name.split(" ").first
  end

  def last_name
    self.last_name = self.name.split(" ").last
  end
end
```

So, I am curious if the method "set_first_last" name is called and it sees that the attribute first_name on user is blank it will call the method "first_name", correct?  The attribute first_name on user is different than a method called "first_name."  So an attribute on the user object called "first_name" would be different than a method on the user class called "first_name" in Rails, correct?  This would be like a class level method vs an instance method?   Just want to be sure I am correct and that I am explaining this correctly.

thanks

--Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the part I think I understand: yes, an attribute on a model is quite different than a method.

Take, for example, a User model, a Users controller, and one of its corresponding views. Let's pretend the User model itself contains `first_name`, `last_name`, and `email` properties:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  #Ensure presence of the following before saving model
  validates_presence_of :first_name, :last_name, :email 

  #Verify unique email
  validates_uniqueness_of :email

  #Here's our lone User method...poor guy
  def admin?
    self.company_members.where('? = ANY (company_members.roles)', Role::ADMIN).any?
  end
end
```

When you get around to working with an *instance* of that model in your controller, it'll look something like this:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    #Let's just grab a random user
    @user = User.find(1)
  end
end
```

Finally, in your view, your properties (attributes) can be accessed in the following way:

```
####views/users/index.html.haml####

.random-class
  = "You're logged in as #{@user.first_name}!"
```

But we can also call User *methods* in the view as well. Continuing off our last example, we could add something like this:

```
####views/users/index.html.haml####

.random-class
  = "You're logged in as #{@user.first_name}!"
  - if @user.admin?
    = 'Oh my gosh, our freaking User method worked!'
```

So in short, you're correct in that properties and methods are very different, although they look similar at times.

Lastly, it's worth pointing out that instance methods are just that: methods called on *instances* of a class, whereas *class methods* are called on an actual model object, and not a singular instance of that model object. [Here's a great link to learn more about the differences.](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: When you do `@user.first_name` you are most definitely calling a method called `first_name` (Which then calls read_attribute)

Comment: You're absolutely right, Frederick. I was trying to boil this down in to lamens terms, though, without having to explain the entire stack of processes that occurs. I think Mike was just looking for quick verification. Thanks for further clarifying, though.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are misreading this bit of the code:

```
def set_first_last
  first_name if self.first_name.blank?
  last_name if self.last_name.blank?
end
```

This code calls the `first_name` method, and if it is blank, calls the `first_name` method again (in other words the `if` parts of this method are pointless)

The way this code is constructed, the value of the first_name and last_name attributes will never be used (other than if you were to use them in your queries) - any time you do `user.first_name` it will reconstruct it from `name`. A more common pattern would be to have the methods that set the names called something like `ensure_first_name` (Basically anything that doesn't class with the getter)

Instance variables (eg @foo) are distinct from methods of the same name, although it is of course common for `foo` and `foo=` to be the methods for getting/setting an instance variable of that name. Perhaps you were thinking of that? In an event the attributes of an Activerecord model aren't stored in individual instance variables.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, what you explained is correct. 
Your piece of coding is going to work and assign the first_name & last_name with the splitted form. 
further you can write your code in this way as well (assuming your full name consists of 2 words separated by space)**

```
 #user.rb
class user     
  before_save :assign_individual_names

 private 
  def assign_individual_names
    first_name, last_name = name.split(' ')
  end

end
```